# React + Typescript: copying props of a custom component - React.PropsWithoutRef doesn't work for me

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that wraps `Router` and takes an additional props. I tried using `PropsWithoutRef` in a way that's analogous to the use in [**this cheatsheet**](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples):

```
import React, { ComponentType, PropsWithoutRef } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'

type LayoutRouteProps = PropsWithoutRef<Route> & {
    component: ComponentType,
};


const DashboardLayoutRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}: LayoutRouteProps) => {
    const render = (props: any)=> <Component {...props} />

    return <Route {...rest} render={render} />
};
```

But it did no good. When I try to use `DashboardLayoutRoute` and pass props relevant to `Route`:

```
<DashboardLayoutRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
```

I get

> Error:(63, 39) TS2322: Type '{ exact: true; path: string; component: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Route & { component: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
>
> > Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Route & { component: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
>
> Error:(66, 39) TS2322: Type '{ path: string; component: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Route & { component: ComponentType<{}>; }'.
>
> > Property 'path' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Route & { component: ComponentType<{}>; }'.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution further [**in the same cheatsheet**](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#the-types-i-need-werent-exported)!

The correct way to extract props from a component is not via `PropsWithoutRef` but via `React.ComponentProps` (or `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef`) in combination with `typeof`:

```
import React, { ComponentType, ComponentProps } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'

type LayoutRouteProps = ComponentProps<typeof Route> & {
    component: ComponentType,
};
```

But as Mor Shemesh pointed out in his answer, it's probably better to import the type instead when you can:

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react'
import { Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router'


type LayoutRouteProps = RouterProps & {
    component: ComponentType,
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, wish I could upvote several more times.  Regarding the cheat sheet, are we actually required to dig through tombs of esoteric typescript instructions in a nook-and-cranny website on the far corners of the internet just to find to one diamond in the ruff?  Or, is there a more reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend using the

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Route, RouteProps } from "react-router";

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Home</div>;
    }
}

type LayoutRouteProps = RouteProps & {
    component: React.ComponentType;
}

const DashboardLayoutRoute = ({
    component, 
    ...rest
    }: LayoutRouteProps) => {
        const ComponentClass = component;
        const render = (props: any) => <ComponentClass {...props} />;

        return <Route {...rest} render={render} />;
}

const renderRoot = () => (
    <DashboardLayoutRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
);
```

Comment: True true, probably best to import the type when you can!